# Find the difference between two similar Objects

Tags: java, eclipse, comparison

I am debugging Javascript code for Android.
I need to know the differences between one object that behaves OK and another object, same class, similar to the first, but behaves badly.
These objects are comprised of a lot of members, and I want to pinpoint which difference between them may be causing the different behavior.
Can it be done with Eclipse built-in functions? During runtime?

Comment: You could write a compare function and then invoke it on your two objects...

Comment: Yes, that's right. A lot of work though.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me. You only have to iterate over the properties of those objects and compare the values...

Comment: Are you only concerned about the own properties of those objects, or the inherited ones too?

Comment: I want to find the difference all the way down the hierarchy whatever it may be. BTW, did you see how many members a Button or TableRow have? It **is** a lot of work, unless you know some piece of code that iterates automatically through the hierarchy.

Comment: Well, obviously you want to iterate with a loop, LOL. We are programmers, not toilers `:P`

Comment: Are the objects of the same class? (Do they have the same prototype link?)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can follow this tricky way :

1. Place a Conditional Breakpoint when you need to compare the two objects
2. Inside the condition put code to serialize the two Objects (for example with a `toJSON` function)
3. Compare the output of the serialization(JSON) with the text compare tool

Comment: I think that's a bad idea. (For one thing, the properties of objects are not ordered, so you could have a false negative just because the order is not the same.) There is no reason to avoid comparing the objects directly by iterating over its properties.

Comment: aleroot, can you be more specific. I don't know much about JSON. You mean to put code to flush the serialized data into a file?  Can you post a few lines example?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://blog.stchur.com/2007/04/06/serializing-objects-in-javascript/ good blog post for more information on how to serialize objects in JS.

Comment: @aleroot I corrected the question, I meant java code (compiled) not javascript (interpreted). The blog you pointed to is specific for javascript not applicable for java :(

Comment: You can do the same thing in Java serializing the object, the technique is the same ...